# linux(ubuntu) shell window width

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

anyone knows how to change the default width for shell window in Linux(Ubuntu), so that I don't have to re-size it every time I open it up? Thanks

Comment: right cilck on the window (assuming this is X) and go to edit and adjust ... save / make default ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Run `gconf-editor`, navigate to `/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default` and set the `default_size_columns` and `default_size_rows` keys.  The columns & rows are measured in characters, not in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on gnome:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry 120x60
```

Will explicitly state the window size. `konsole` sounds like KDE's variant. The same argument should work there.